# what are the available values of 'ui' config option

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2 there is a  config option `ui` for every component. In the examples only `dark`, `plain` values are used here. I want to know what are the other options?

Also how can I add my own option? like `ui: 'mytheme'`

Comment: Like this? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ui" option has different values depending on where you use it. For example, in a `xtype:button` it can be things like ["back", "confirm", "normal", etc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-ui), but for a `xtype:panel` you only have ["light" or "dark"](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-ui).

As @sajawikio commented, if you're looking to theme the entire app, then look at the documentation for [building themes](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_theme).